# how to store an external api json value in a multikeymap and loop over it to remove hardcoded code and make it dynamic?

Tags: java

i hava a json response from an external api like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {

                 "id": 1,

                 "airline_code": "7634",

                 "supplier_code": "G8",

                 "portal_configuration_id": 1,

                 "enabled": true,

                 "micro_service_name": "booking"
        }
    ]
}
```

the response should be dynamic
How to put this and get it using multikeymap
The code in Spring boot is

```
if (spicejetEnabled) {

                        Request searchRequest = new Request.Builder().url(spicejetServiceUrl + "/spicejet/v1.0/search").post(body)

                                .addHeader("X-AFFILIATE-ID", request.getHeader("X-AFFILIATE-ID")).addHeader("X-AFFILIATE-NAME", request.getHeader("X-AFFILIATE-NAME"))
                                .addHeader("X-XL-CODE", request.getHeader("X-XL-CODE")).addHeader("X-SEARCH-ID", uuId).build();
                        Call call = client.newCall(searchRequest);
                        call.enqueue(new Callback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                MDC.setContextMap(mdcContext);
                                LOG.debug("spicejet responded success, status Code: " + response.code());

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                                MDC.setContextMap(MDC.getCopyOfContextMap());
                                LOG.error("Failure, Reason For Spicejet: ", e);

                            }
                        });
                        supplierCount++;
                        LOG.info("Search initiated for Spicejet " + spicejetServiceUrl + "/spicejet/v1.0/search");
                    }
```

there are multiple lines of code like this with just airline name changed.In order to disable a flight we have to comment that airline block of code.

oktthpclient has been used to store to call the API

This is my code that I have added and startUrl is the value I am injecting from application.propeties and whose json value I have to map and inject it to other controller classes:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();       
                        Request getActiveMicroservicesRequest = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(startUrl)
                                .get()
                                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json-patch+json")
                                .build();
                        Response getActiveMicroservicesResponse = client.newCall(getActiveMicroservicesRequest).execute();
```

Comment: Are  you using RestTemplate or FeignClient from Spring or WebTarget.
 
Can you share the code to invoke the client code.

Comment: I have added some code please have a look and tell me if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

Keep this code inside onResponse method

```
  String message = response.body().string();
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(respone);
  ArrayNode data = (ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("data");
  TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {};
  Map<String, Object> mapping = mapper.readValue(data.get(0).toString(), typeRef);
```

Comment: i have done some code like this , I will also add that in my question.